# Is there a standard WPF stylesheet for a "Microsoft" look?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is there somewhere some polished stylesheet (and guidelines for its usage) that can be applied to any window to give it a proper "Microsoft" look?

In my case / example I have a simple window:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Header="My checkboxes">
          <StackPanel >
                <CheckBox>First</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Second</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox>Third</CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button>OK</Button>
            <Button>Cancel</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I can think of the following styles group

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,8,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="70"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Together with this change of the first checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Margin="0">First</CheckBox>
```

It makes the window look this way:

[image]

It's not perfect, but it's much better than it was without styles applied.

Answer (score 2):

You could find 7 WPF Themes by Microsoft on [WPF Toolkit page](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes).

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I need. I need proper sizes and margins to all controls, and the themes on that page only change colors.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also interested in this. For CSS there are several common style sheets for best practice layout.